# What is a sustainable way of removing oil stains from my concrete driveway?

Tags: pollution, oil

Yes, I know that having a car is unsustainable, but nevertheless I'm interested in the most sustainable way to remove an oil stain from my driveway.

Unsustainable suggestions I've had include using kitty litter (mining [bentonite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentonite) is hardly sustainable), and chemical degreasers (probably petroleum based).

Obviously used oil from a car is pretty toxic, so there's probably no avoiding sending the material I use to soak up the oil to landfill (unless perhaps it's safe to burn in small quantities in a hot fire, depending on what material I soak it up into?). However using a material that has the lowest possible environmental impact is something I can control.

Comment: Why would mining bentonite be unstustainable.  It is a stable compound that does not create hazardous waste.  You will be using a very finite amount for a very specific purpose.  It is not like you need to do the mining it is a by product of mining several other ore that are already mined.  Everyone needed to remove an oil stain a week and maybe even a day I doubt we would run out of it.

Comment: @Chad, my understanding is that because it's used for cat litter, there is already an enormous demand for it. It can only be used once, and won't re-accumulate within any reasonable period, which makes it unsustainable by definition, no matter what the size of the reserves.

Comment: I think you underestimate the reserves of this.  The only thing that is unsustainable about this process would be the oil, but that is already there you are just putting it into a medium that is actually going to improve the oils reclamation rate, and prevent it from contaminating runoff.  This would be more sustainable than just leaving the stain for sure.  And definitely better than any chemical cleaning agent I know of.

Comment: I'm going to make a joke response: Sell your car get rid of the driveway, bike to work and turn the driveway into a garden. This really may be the most sustainable answer TBH. LOL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just changed the oil, ground cork or sawdust works well. If the oil has been sitting there then try distilled white vinegar with baking soda. Take a shop broom or large brush with hard bristles and put some muscle into it. It may take a few rounds.